# docker-compose up error from external disk: no such image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've changed the docker directory to an external pendrive (ntfs) by creating the `daemon.json` file:

```
{ 
   "graph": "/external-disk-path/docker" 
}
```

And this is my docker compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

However, I am getting this error everytime I run `docker-compose up`:

```
level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.25/images/redis:latest/json returned error: No such image: redis:latest
```

It happens with every image, redis is just an example...

Some information:

`docker images` and `docker ps -a` are empty, and I am using ubuntu 16.04 and docker 17.03.0-ce.

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: already tried with a newer docker version, 20.10.7, and the error persists. The pendrive and the filesystem gets stuck when I run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: The graph option was [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#-g-and---graph-flags-on-dockerd). I doubt that the new "data-root" option would solve your issue but it wouldn't hurt I guess. Did you restart your the docker daemon afterwards?

Comment: @pat `data-root` doesn't work, I had to use `graph`, and yes, I stopped and then started the `docker.service`, all sub-folders were created sucessfully...